# Attempting to lock an excel file for a limited amount of time

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two desires that I'm attempting to acheive in an excel spreadsheet.

1) I want the spreadsheet to be editable only during a limited amount of hours during a day. Between 10:30am and 2:30pm. Is this possible?

2) I also want it, when the user edits this spreadsheet, to automatically time stamp so I can indicate when the edit occurred. So if I edit cell A1 at 11am, I want (anywhere, in another cell) to time stamp indicating when that change occured. Is this possible.

I am using excel 2013

Comment: You can get closer with a macro, but I believe Excel isn't the right tool for that. Either Access or a SharePoint site would be a better choice for that.

Comment: I agree not the right tool, but you can use a workbook open event that checks `now()` of course if the user can change their clock..